# Implementing arithmetic modulo N with contracts

Tags: racket

I'm trying to implement arithmetic in a field modulo N. Here's a simplified example:

```
(struct field-element (number prime) #:transparent)

(define (field-element-add fe1 fe2)
  (field-element (modulo (+ (field-element-number fe1)
                            (field-element-number fe2))
                         (field-element-prime fe1))
                 (field-element-prime fe1)))

(field-element-add (field-element 3 5) (field-element 4 5))    ; (1)
(field-element-add (field-element 3 5) (field-element 4 6))    ; (2)
```

(1) should return `(field-element 2 5)` because `3 + 4 = 7 = 2 mod 5`

(2) should raise an error, because you can't add elements in fields with different prime modulus (5 and 6 in this example).

My question: how to use contracts that check all arguments to `field-element-add` share the same `prime` and raise errors when they don't?

All the contracts I've seen in the [docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/contracts-general-functions.html) enforce constraints on each argument separately e.g. `integer?`. But I want to enforce a constraint across the arguments as a group: they must share a `prime` property.

And I know I could just check this manually without a contract -- but this seems like exactly the circumstance contracts were made for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: btw I have math operators for `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` as recommended in [part 3 of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55876455/using-built-in-math-operators-with-custom-struct/55876909#55876909). It would be great to define some custom contract that can easily apply to each of these ...

Answer (score 2):

In the page that you mentioned, take a look at section [7.3.6](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/contracts-general-functions.html#%28part._contracts-arrow-d%29) for how to use `->i` so that you can "mention" other arguments.

For your case:

```
(struct field-element (number prime) #:transparent)

(define field-binop/c
  (->i ([a field-element?]
        [b (a) (struct/c field-element
                         number?
                         (=/c (field-element-prime a)))])
       [result field-element?]))

(define/contract (field-element-add fe1 fe2) field-binop/c
  (field-element (modulo (+ (field-element-number fe1)
                            (field-element-number fe2))
                         (field-element-prime fe1))
                 (field-element-prime fe1)))

(field-element-add (field-element 3 5) (field-element 4 5)) ;=> (field-element 2 5)
(field-element-add (field-element 3 5) (field-element 4 6))

#|
../../Applications/Racket v7.2/collects/racket/contract/private/blame.rkt:347:0: field-element-add: contract violation
  expected: (struct/c field-element number? (=/c 5))
  given: (field-element 4 6)
  in: the fe2 argument of
      (->i
       ((fe1 field-element?)
        (fe2
         (fe1)
         (struct/c
          field-element
          number?
          (=/c (field-element-prime fe1)))))
       (result field-element?))
  contract from: (function field-element-add)
  blaming: anonymous-module
   (assuming the contract is correct)
  at: unsaved-editor:5.18
|#
```

Comment: Thanks! Let's say that I also have `field-element-subtract`, `field-element-multiply` and `field-element-divide` which share this same "signature". Is there a nice way to abstract the `(->i ... )` chunk so that it can be nicely applied to these 4 functions without having to repeat the code 4 times?

Comment: Also -- how can one place this code on a `#:methods gen:addable` struct method as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55876455/using-built-in-math-operators-with-custom-struct/55876909#55876909)? In this case, `field-element?` isn't defined yet because this code exists on the struct's definition (it seems) ...

Comment: Re: your first comment, contract is just a regular value in Racket, so you can abstract it out. See my updated answer.

Comment: Re: your second comment, this is a good question. I don't really know what's the best solution here. You might create a new question asking how to attach a contract that uses struct defined functions to a struct method. Note that in the method body everything is already defined, so I guess one very hacky workaround is to define a helper function after the struct definition with a contract on it, and then invoke the helper function inside the method.

Comment: Also note that if you only want `+` to additionally work for `field-element`, you could use solution (2) in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55876455/using-built-in-math-operators-with-custom-struct/55876909#55876909, and with it, you don't need to bother with struct methods.